# How load class for automation with MFC

Tags: automation, mfc, com

I want to load class of an application with MFC project and use them for software automation.The project type is MFC application my compiler is visual studio 2012 . I loaded class from typelib wizard. whole of my code is:

my code is :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCApplication1.h"
#include "CGPNSApplicationDisp.h"
#include "ChildFrm.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

 void CChildFrame::AssertValid() const
    {

CLSID clsid;
LPDISPATCH pWMPDispatch = NULL;
::CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("SGNSAutomation.SGNSApplication"), &clsid);
IID iid;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, 
  IID_IDispatch, (LPVOID*)&pWMPDispatch);//creating base class of application
  CGPNSApplicationDisp *GPNSApplication1;
 hr=pWMPDispatch->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IGPNSApplicationDisp), 
  (void**)&GPNSApplication1);
 LPDISPATCH  myNet = NULL;
 myNet=GPNSApplication1->addSimulationCase();//error occured here
 ISimulationCaseDisp* mysym= NULL;
 mysym=GPNSApplication1->openCase(myfile.c_str());*/
 CMDIChildWndEx::AssertValid();
```

}

list of method for CGPNSApplicaionDisp:
addSimulationCase()
getSimulationCase(file path)
importCase(file path)
openCase(file path)

an error occurred when the program want to invoke this method in the oledisp2.cpp
in the line :
     SCODE sc = m_lpDispatch->Invoke(dwDispID, IID_NULL, 0, wFlags,
        &dispparams, pvarResult, &excepInfo, &nArgErr);
error is Unhandled exception at 0x0FB3F03A (mfc110ud.dll) in MFCApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000002. 
   I am not a professional in MFC project and COM interface.
   Please help me.
   Thank You.

Comment: You are defining a pointer (`GPNSApplication1`), assign a `nullptr` to it, and then dereference it. Did you not expect to get the moral equivalent of a NULL pointer exception? And if so, why?

Comment: Tanks for your response Can you help me to define it? if i don't assign nullptr uninitialized error occur.

Comment: I defined pointer  CGPNSApplicationDisp *GPNSApplication1=new CGPNSApplicationDisp();  my problem solved but GPNSApplication1->addSimulationCase() return 0xcccccccc How Can  I solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot expect to write COM code without knowing even the most trivial COM basics. It appears that you are also lacking basic understanding of C and C++. You need to fix that.

Comment: Thanks you. I think you misunderstand my question.

Comment: I do understand your question. I don't understand your expectations. COM object instances are created using [`CoCreateInstanceEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680701.aspx). That's fundamental COM. You are trying to use a technology you do not understand, using a programming language you do not understand. *That* is the real issue at hand. And Stack Overflow is not the place that holds your hand through your baby steps. I'm afraid.

Comment: I added typelib library of my applicaion in MFC Project. I used coCreateinstance but access violation occur when MFC want to invoke addsimulationCase() method in oledisp2.cpp

in this line:
SCODE sc = m_lpDispatch->Invoke(dwDispID, IID_NULL, 0, wFlags,
  &dispparams, pvarResult, &excepInfo, &nArgErr);

Comment: With the information provided we can only conclude, that you are doing it wrong. If you are looking for more substantial information, provide a [mcve], including a proper problem statement.

Comment: @mahdiLotfi : This is almost certainly a problem with your DISPPARAMS. As @IInspectable stated, we need to see more of your code. The code you provided has an obvious problem (`GPNSApplication1` is never set to anything), but it sounds like the code you're working with is not the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I am not a professional in COM interface, but its a dire need for my project.
I modified my code and edit it to final version and with more detail I hope my question be obvious and you can help me.
thanks